# Heroku deployment error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

Tags: python

I am trying to deploy my python web application to Heroku and I am using the postgresql database to store user information such as login credentials etc. My app has been deployed but I am trying to create the database table by running the commands

```
Heroku run python
from app import db
db.create_all()
```

However, when I run that in my terminal, I receive this error message.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'.
```

I have tried to run `pip install pyscopg2` and then I receive this error

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.
```

I have also ran the command `pip install psycopg2-binary`  and receive the same error. Any explantation for how I can resolve this... Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add a file in the root directory of your project named `requirements.txt` with the following contents:

```
psycopg2
```

Heroku also reccommends adding a version number like so:

```
psycopg2==2.9.3
```

Learn more here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip